# Flutter - How to tap automatically a button inside a WebView in the middle of screen?

Tags: flutter, webview, gesturedetector

I am using [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) plugin to load an embed video url, after the video is loaded I needed an automatic tap in the middle of screen, to simulate an autoplay, since the host I am using doesn't support  it (iframe).

```
return Container(
            color: Colors.black,
            width: getWidth(context),
            height: getHeight(context),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: WebView(
              initialUrl: Uri.dataFromString(uri, mimeType: 'text/html').toString(),
              javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
              
            ),
          );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can play it by default/automatically.

Use this plugin : `flutter_webview_plugin: ^0.3.11`.

Now use `mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture: false,` to autoplay your video.

```
WebviewScaffold(
    mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture: false,
    initialChild: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
    withJavascript: true,
    url:'',
),
```